# Find the solution of $ y'=y^2/x+y/2x+1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I can't find particular solution of:
$$y'=\dfrac {y^2}x+\dfrac y {2x}+1$$

**My attempts:**

I tried $y(x)=x^n$ and $y(x)=e^{ax}$ etc. But It didn't work.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Y=x^n  And y=e^ax etc

Comment: Your equation is ambiguous.  Please put parentheses around the fractions you intend to designate.

Comment: What do you call "special solution" ?

Comment: I believe he is searching/asking for some particular solution for above Riccati's equation...

Comment: Yes I try to find a particular solution but I can't

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

Answer (score 2):

$$y'=y^2/x+y/2x+1$$
This is Riccati's differential equation.

Multiply by $\sqrt x$
$$\sqrt x y'-\dfrac y {2\sqrt x}=\dfrac {y^2}{\sqrt x}+\sqrt x$$
$$\left (\dfrac y {\sqrt x}\right)' =\dfrac {y^2}{x\sqrt x}+\dfrac 1 {\sqrt x}$$
$$\left (\dfrac y {\sqrt x}\right)' =\dfrac 1 {\sqrt x}  \left (\dfrac {y^2}{x}+1 \right)$$
It's separable. Integrate.
$$\dfrac {du}{u^2+1}=\dfrac {dx} {\sqrt x} $$
Where $u=\dfrac y {\sqrt x}$
$$\implies \arctan u = 2\sqrt x+C$$
$$\boxed {y(x)= {\sqrt x} \tan ( 2 {\sqrt x}+C)}$$